# A geometry problem (how to find angle x)

Tags: geometry

[image]

The solution is $x=50^{\circ}$.

How to prove $x=50^{\circ}$ without trigonometry?

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Find $K$ on $\overline{BD}$ such that $\angle KAB = 10^\circ$. Then $\angle AKB = 160^\circ = 2\cdot\angle ACB$; this makes $K$ the center of the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$. Thus, $\overline{KB}\cong\overline{KC}$, whereupon $\angle KCB = 20^\circ$. Note also that $\triangle ACK$ must be equilateral. (Why?)

We also have that $\angle DKA = 20^\circ = \angle DAK$. This makes $\triangle DAK$ isosceles, so that $\overline{CD}$ bisects $\angle ACK = 60^\circ$. The result follows. $\square$

Comment: (+1) Think I got that. Have you used the identified $k$ to be the centre of the circle because of the arrow theorem?

Comment: @Karl: Yes. Because the angle at $K$ looking at $\overline{AB}$ is twice the angle at $C$ looking at $\overline{AB}$, the Arrow Theorem implies that $K$ is the circumcenter of $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: I have learnt something in attempting to answer this and from seeing your answer. It deserves to be accepted as the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @abiessu: Isn't $\angle CAD = 40^\circ$ in the question's diagram?

Comment: @Blue: of course, if I miss a simple flip and slight rotation, I would miss the correctness of the answer...

Answer (score -2):

**This is incorrect and just left for reference**

The strategy to take appears to be to find all the angles in the centre at $D$  in terms of $x$ and then equate to $360$ but I don't get $x=50$

$\angle BDC=180-20-x=160-x$

$\angle ADB=180-30-10=140$

Use the largest triangle to find $\angle ACD$

$\angle ACD =180-70-30-x=80-x$

This means $\angle ADC =180-40-(80-x)=60+x$

At the centre you have $160-x+140+60+x=360$

The $x$ cancel and I briefly checked that $x=60$ is a solution as well.

**See comments below as to why this fails**

Comment: If $x$ cancels, then you can't solve for it. Moreover, it certainly isn't possible to find an alternate solution: $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle ADC$ are uniquely determined by the angles at $A$ and $B$ (and the length of $\overline{AB}$); consequently, the entire figure is fixed, so that $x$ has *exactly one* value. (A GeoGebra sketch seems to confirm that $x=50^\circ$, but I don't have a non-trigonometric proof.)

Comment: I had horrible feelings about this one. Shall I leave my misendeavour or delete it?

Comment: Put comment on showing my error. Thanks.

Comment: You're a teacher, so you could transform this to a teachable moment. Edit to declare the answer incorrect, and then explain *why* it is incorrect. After all, many students are bound to make this kind of mistake themselves. (Ah ... You've edited just as I've written this. I guess I'm more persuasive than I realized. ;)

Comment: It is the uniquely determined bit that tripped me up. I need to think that through.